# preg_replace returns empty string (without matching)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to use preg_replace on a string, but although the string does not match, I get an empty string as return string.

```
PHP Code:
    $sql = "k1 LIKE 'n' OR k2 LIKE 'n' OR k3 LIKE 'n' OR k4 LIKE 'n' OR k5 LIKE 'n' OR k6 LIKE '1' ";
    print "SQL: $sql<br>";
    $sql_A = preg_replace("/^([\w]+ LIKE\s?'?.*?'? OR )+ $/", "##$1##", $sql);
    print "=> $sql_A<br>";
```

returns:

> ```
> SQL: k1 LIKE 'n' OR k2 LIKE 'n' OR k3 LIKE 'n' OR k4 LIKE 'n' OR k5 LIKE 'n' OR k6 LIKE '1'
> =>
> ```

The weird thing is, the regex doesn't even match. 
I tried to simplify the string the most I could while getting the same result. I also might add an OR just before the end-$. But as soon as I drop some more or add sth. else, I get the normal behavior and the right replacement.

Does anyone see why this happenes? Maybe I made a mistake I'm not seeing, maybe this is a bug? 
I'm lost...

(Using PHP Version 5.3.21 on a LINUX Server)

--- 2013-04-24 21:30 ---

Edit:

If it helps, my originally used data was:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS anz FROM xxx_table LEFT JOIN yyy_table on yyy_table.devo=xxx_table.devo LEFT JOIN zzz_table ON (yyy_table.status=zzz_table.sid AND lang=1 AND yyy_table.for =zzz_table.for) LEFT JOIN kunde k on k.kd_nr = yyy_table.kd_nr LEFT JOIN locations l on l.lok_nr = yyy_table.lok_nr WHERE xxx_table.clear!='Y' AND xxx_table.ign!='Y' AND name NOT LIKE 'Container:%' AND name LIKE '%' AND event_prio LIKE '%' AND zzz_table.show='Y' AND ( k.ikd_nr LIKE '%n%' OR k.such LIKE '%n%' OR k.adr1 LIKE '%n%' OR k.adr2 LIKE '%n%' OR k.ort LIKE '%n%' OR k.strasse LIKE '%n%' )";
$sql_A = preg_replace("/(\((\s*[\w\.\-\`]+ (LIKE\s|=)\s*'?.+?'?\s*OR)* [\w\.\-\`]+ LIKE '%' (OR [\w\.\-\`]+ (LIKE\s|=)\s*'?.+?'?\s*)*\))/i", "", $sql);
```

And again, the result was NULL (not an empty string as I have learned ;) 
(Purpuse of this preg_replace is, to identify OR-conditions in SQL statements with LIKE '%' patterns to remove those unnecessary OR-conditions.)

Comment: `If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) ... so there is probably an error with the pattern. The main one might be `[\w]` which should be `\w` in PHP. There are a few more issues with the pattern though. What is the desired output?

Comment: With the anchors, doesn't this expression require the string to end with `OR  ` ("OR" plus two spaces)?

Comment: @Wiseguy it does... if it was working it would also replace the entire string with the last capture. That's what I meant with "there are a few more issuess"... but without the desired output, trying to fix it is just wild guesses

Comment: @m.buettner Agreed. I wasn't addressing you specifically, just pointing out my first observation about the pattern. To address you specifically, I don't think `[\w]` would be a problem. The `[ ]` is unnecessary, but I believe it's still functionally equivalent to simply `\w`.

Comment: @Wiseguy hm you're right. I actually thought so too, but removing the square brackets also seemed remove the error for some obscure reason.

Comment: It's not an error with the pattern. If I add "888" at the beginning og the $sql it works as desired. Which means, it's the combo of the string and the regex (and the preg_replace).

Comment: And yes, it shouldn't match because the string does not end with an OR. But as I said, it's not that it matches and replaces, it simply returns an empty string, which it should not at any case.

Comment: @rItlha' it does not return an emptry string (see Wrikken's answer)... it returns NULL due to an error. again, what is your desired output?

Comment: my desired output is the original $sql string. Because there is no match, I don't want any changes.

Comment: Well, of course the whole thing is a bit more complicated. I want to match a sql statement with special OR conditions. It worked fine until I got one sql statement which returned NULL. So I broke the statement and the regex into the smallest pices I could to identify the problem.

Comment: PLEASE, give us the desired output!

Comment: desired output for the example is: "k1 LIKE 'n' OR k2 LIKE 'n' OR k3 LIKE 'n' OR k4 LIKE 'n' OR k5 LIKE 'n' OR k6 LIKE '1' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is built in a way that it consumes enormous amounts of backtracks:

```
 echo preg_ last_ error()
```

Yields `2` (`PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`)

You could of course increase the backtrack:

```
 ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit",100000000);
```

... which would make this regex not work (as it doesn't match), but it would at least return the original string. Creating a more efficient regex seems more attractive, but to make a stab at that I would need a desired input & output.

**edit:**

Looking at it some more, I think this regex might help you on your way a little:

```
$sql_A = preg_replace(
   "/(\w+ LIKE\s*('(\\\.|[^'\\\]|)*'|[^\s]+))/",
   "##<$1>##",
   $sql);
```

Comment: Oh. I never that about backtracks... I think I have to read a bit about it. Don't even know, what a backtrack is or why it is produced...

Comment: Backtracks is what the regex engine uses internally to verify a match (it's just what makes them work). The main problem in your regex is the `'?.*?'?`, which not really limits the match-possibilities, making the engine having to check a lot of permutations before arriving at the correct one (or none as now).

Comment: @rItlha' [have a look here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the idea now. So I'll try to use Wrikkens (x|y) suggestion in future instead of stuff like '?.*?'?

Comment: @Wrikken Just to clearlify, you  mean, my problem is/was that there were too many backtracks? I tried the (x|y) for the quotes now and I get the an output. But as I mentioned before, when I only change some other small parts of the regex, I did get an output before as well. (But it would seem logical for me know, that the backtracks caused the NULL return.)

Comment: Yes, ineed, mainly by `'?.*?'?` (which makes the `.*?` not having a definitive start or end. From the excellent link m.buettner provided: if we change the inside to `(\\\.|[^'\\\]|)*'|[^'\s]+) `  (note the extra `'` in `[^'\s]`, and ending space / ` `), the solution matches the remark there _"About the only situation where they don't is when the start of each alternative inside the group is not optional, and mutually exclusive with the start of all the other alternatives, and mutually exclusive with the token that follows it"_

Comment: Why do you use \\\ ? What's it supposed to do? [^'] would mean "everything except a '", right? I changed that part of the regex to (('.*?')|(.*?)) which does the job nicely (as I think).

Comment: \\\ matches a _single_ \ (needs to be escaped twice), What it does there is match anything not `'` or \, or if it matches a \, it is an escape character and the content of the next character is ignored / not limited (`.`=all). It's to match strings like: `OR name LIKE 'O\'reilly'`.

Comment: Oh, and `('.*?')|(.*?)` can, and probably  will, exhibit the same problems as your previous regex, maybe just a little bit later. It no longer makes to the subpatterns mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I got your regex finally:) It's cool.
 But I'm still not quite sure about why my solution is worse (except for the \' - which I didn't think of). Is it that I use '.*?' while you write '[^']*?' . I thought if I use *? it's not greedy, meaning it stops at the first appearance of '. Maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "k1 LIKE 'n' OR k2 LIKE 'n' OR k3 LIKE 'n' OR k4 LIKE 'n' OR k5 LIKE 'n' OR k6 LIKE '1' ";
$pattern = "~(?>\w++(?>\.\w++)?\h++LIKE\h++'[^']++'\h++OR\h++)*+\w++(?>\.\w++)?\h++LIKE\h++'[^']++'~";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "##$0##",$sql);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: This works. But I don't understand parts of the regex. The tilde is used as a delimitar as far as I see. But is (?> some kind of look-ahead/behind? (Can't find it with a search enginges as they just skip those letters:) And what does \w++ do? (has ++ a special meaning)?